# will .tk domain get indexed on google what are its disadvantages

Tags: google, domains, top-level-domains

I configured dns of .tk with blogger and made it work as website as it can have many webpages, but now I have some doubts: will .tk (free domains) get indexed on search engines like google, yahoo, etc?

Are there any example .tk domains being indexed on google?

Comment: If you worry about SEO, its really a tiny investment to buy a .com domain, which are like $5-15/yr.

Answer (score 1):

Google does not care whether you paid or not for the domain. But it does care how you did SEO.
So, submit your site to google (http://www.google.com.au/addurl/?continue=/addurl) and please do optimization of the content, get inward links etc if you want your site to start coming up in search results.

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine, but consider [adding your site to Google](http://www.google.com.au/addurl/?continue=/addurl) to speed it up.